# How to debug C++ for pybind11 in visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, debugging, pybind11

I am having a problem to debug the C++ side library code driven by a python application via pybind11. I let the python side sleep for a while before calling the C++ library, then attach the C++ library to the python exe, but was told the symbols on the C++ side are not loaded and therefore the breakpoints will not be reached. Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: *Anyone has a better idea?* -- There is no "better idea" -- you're simply doing something wrong if the C++ code was built with symbols.  The only other idea is to start your python program from Visual Studio instead of attaching.  The debug options in VS has an "Application" setting, and that is where you put in the application to start.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you!